# Git rebase: force push or pull push

Tags: git, github, version-control

We are discussing here in the company about what to do after the `git rebase`. After you `rebase` you need to push the changes to remote `origin` but how should we do it when the git do not allow? Actually, we are discussing about the two ways that we most use when that branch has already been pushed:

**1**. `git push -uf origin branch`

Reasons: only the commits of the branch in the `origin`. The tree will be `flat`.

```
|
|
|
```

**2**.

```
git push -u origin branch
! [rejected]
  hint: Updates where rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
  hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
  hint: "git pull ...") before pushing again.
git pull origin branch
git push -u origin branch
```

Reasons: it'll create a commit named "Merged origin/branch into branch blablabla" that looks like unnecessary. It will not `flap` the tree.

```
|\
| |
|/
```

** The force flag looks weird

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you rebase a branch you are **rewriting the history of that branch**.

If that branch has already been pushed you need to "force push" it since it's new tip is not reachable by it's previous tip (that is why you are getting that error message).

```
git push --force origin branch
```

Comment: Ok, but it looks weird didnt it? Use the force flag almost every time

Comment: It may look weird, but Git wants you to be careful when changing the history of a branch